# Inconsistent behavior of `Intl.toLocaleTimeString` for UK locale for short and long format

Tags: javascript, date, localization, internationalization, ecmascript-5

Assuming that the European(UK) locale date format uses **days** before the month and year like this:

`EEE, dd MMM yyyy`

When I use that in `toLocaleTimeString` with option weekday= short, I get inconsistent response. Days come after the month.

> Fri, Sep 27, 2013 18:38:30 United Kingdom Time

However, when I use the weekday=long it will be consistent with expected date format.

> Friday, 27 Sep 2013 18:38:30 United Kingdom Time

Whether using a short format or long I assume it should be consistent and have the days before the months. However, this is not the case, I am not sure if this is a desired behavior or I am missing some point?

Here is the JavaScript Code in Chrome V29:

```
    var options = {
        hour: "2-digit",
        minute: "2-digit",
        second: "2-digit",
        year: "numeric",
        month: "short",
        day: "2-digit",
        hour12: false,
        timeZoneName: "short",

        weekday:"short"  //"long"
    }

    var date = new Date("Fri Sep 27 2013 13:38:30 GMT-0400");
    options.timeZone = 'America/New_York'
    console.log(date.toLocaleDateString("en-us",options))

    options.timeZone = 'Europe/London'
    console.log(date.toLocaleDateString("en-gb",options))
```

Output:

with weekday= short

> Fri, Sep 27, 2013 1:38:30 PM ET
>   Fri, Sep 27, 2013 18:38:30 United Kingdom Time

with weekday= long

> Friday, Sep 27, 2013 1:38:30 PM ET
>   Friday, 27 Sep 2013 18:38:30 United Kingdom Time

Expected:

> Fri, Sep 27, 2013 1:38:30 PM ET
>   Fri, 27 Sep 2013 18:38:30 United Kingdom Time

Comment: I can reproduce it. Why not file it as a bug: http://code.google.com/p/v8-i18n/issues/list

Comment: I created this issue, http://code.google.com/p/v8-i18n/issues/detail?id=34

Comment: To "save a trip" to the v8-i18n issues page: "This bug is ICU 4.6 problem, and it's fixed in ICU 49. We are planning on updating ICU to include this fix in the near future."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can omit the `year` in `options` and get the day-month format correctly but a date string is obviously no good without a `year` value:

```
var options = {
    hour: "2-digit",
    minute: "2-digit",
    second: "2-digit",
    //year: "numeric",
    month: "short",
    day: "2-digit",
    hour12: false,
    timeZoneName: "short",

    weekday:"short"
}
```

Returns:

```
Fri, Sep 27 1:38:30 PM ET
Fri 27 Sep 18:38:30 United Kingdom Time
```

So here is a temporary workaround until we find out what is going on with this; You can set the `weekday` separately for `en-GB` to get the desired outcome, but you end up with long weekday names:

```
var options = {
        hour: "2-digit",
        minute: "2-digit",
        second: "2-digit",
        year: "numeric",
        month: "short",
        day: "2-digit",
        timeZoneName: "short",
        weekday: "short"
}

    var date = new Date("Fri Sep 27 2013 13:38:30 GMT-0400");
    options.timeZone = "America/New_York";
    console.log(date.toLocaleDateString("en-US",options));

    options.timeZone = "Europe/London";
    options.weekday = "long";
    console.log(date.toLocaleDateString("en-GB",options));
```

This returns:

```
Fri, Sep 27, 2013 1:38:30 PM ET
Friday, 27 Sep 2013 18:38:30 United Kingdom Time
```

I'm still trying to find the cause of this. This doesn't seem to be an ICU issue which returns expected values for both locales (see the result for [`en-GB`](http://apps.icu-project.org/icu4jweb/flexTest.jsp?_=en_GB&pat=yMMMEdvHms) and [`en-US`](http://apps.icu-project.org/icu4jweb/flexTest.jsp?_=en_US&pat=yMMMEdvHms)). It might be that asking for a format with short weekday names *and* `year` causes the [format matcher](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/#BasicFormatMatcher) to fall back to `en` (which uses [`E, MMM d y`](http://unicode.org/cldr/trac/browser/tags/release-24/common/main/en.xml#L1964)). Finding out whether this is a defect or not, needs more looking into. I will update here if I find out.

One small note about explicitly setting the `hour12`. Considering that the default value of this is [locale-dependent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString), I believe it's better to leave that out, too (it's overridden anyway as you see in the output time format for `en-GB`).

Comment: Glad. My pleasure. It was a nice surprise for me! :)

Comment: one side effect is I am loosing the date if I not use the `year`

Comment: I updated the answer with a workaround. Still not quite the fix, but better than nothing.